# Agendamento de jobs usando scheduler Oracle

Tags: oracle

Bom dia, boa tarde e boa noite.

Os senhores poderiam me ajudar com um problema em relação a dbms_schedule do oracle.

Eu preciso criar um JOB que inicie todo dia as 22hrs e pare as 4hrs da manhã, porém ele tem que ser executado a cada 1 hora.

Mas eu não consigo fazer o end_date funcionar, sempre que faço o select na tabela "USER_SCHEDULE_JOBS" ele está como NULL.

Código:

```
/* Criação da Schedule para o programa */      

BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE
  (
    schedule_name => 'a_cada_1_hora_a_partir_das_22',
    start_date => systimestamp + 1/24*22,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1',
    end_date => systimestamp + 1/24*4,
    comments => 'Executar a cada 1 hora à partir das 19 horas da noite até 22 horas'
  );
END;
/

/* Criação da JOB para rodar o programa de acordo com a SCHEDULE criada */

BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
  (
    job_name => 'JOB_TESTE_1',
    program_name => 'INSERT_TBL_JOB_TESTE',
    schedule_name => 'a_cada_1_hora_a_partir_das_22',
    enabled => TRUE,
    auto_drop => FALSE,
    comments => 'Executar o programa INSERT_TBL_JOB_TESTE entre 19hrs até 22hrs.'
   );
END;
/
```

Não consegui entender muito bem o que tá na documentação do Oracle e estou tendo dificuldades em programar esse intervalo, poderiam me ajudar?

Obrigado, desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom não teve respostas para o problema porém eu acabei conseguindo a solução aqui, fica ai como ajuda para quem tiver o mesmo problema:

Para configura uma faixa de horário é só usar o "BYHOUR" e passar as horas, ficou assim:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE
  (
    schedule_name => 'a_cada_1_hora_a_partir_das_22',
    start_date => systimestamp,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=22,23,00,01,02,03,04',
    comments => 'Executar a cada 1 hora à partir das 22 horas da noite até 4 horas da manhã'
  );
END;
/
```

Valeu ^^